# Who did the helicopter stunt in “Crossplot”?

Tags: stunts, crossplot

[*Crossplot*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossplot_(film)) (1969) with Roger Moore et al. has a spectacular helicopter vs car chase scene. It ends rather stupidly (the man dangling from the helicopter runs into power lines which somehow causes the helicopter to explode too) but the chase scene is superb, especially when you consider some poor soul had to actually fly the helicopter like that.

Who did it and how was it actually done? I can't find the answer on the internet.

Comment: How much of it is actually miniature work? Some of it was done, uncredited, by Gerry Anderson's Century21 outfit

Comment: I'd say the initial buzz scene was minature work: there is something off about the scale of it all, but the part where the chopper flies along the grass, and buzzes the tractor and the car in the field has to be real - I don't think they could get such realistic scenes with grass moving like that in 1969 via special effects.

Comment: I posted something, but it isnt an answer, as it is not definitive. All I got from it was that the same pilot (and helicopter) is seen in Digby, the biggest dog in the world. In fact the helicopter is in very many tv series and films (Prisoner, Persuaders, Avengers, etc). Different pilots may fly these machines, though the single owner during the period of Crossplot is Ken Gregory, but noted stunt aviator John Crewdson is also known to have flown it as well.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ph50M.png - pilot in Crossplot, same pilot in Digby https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FPuT.png - this is the helicopter used (crashed in 1973) - https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzFDx.png

Comment: yes, just the last few (IMHO obvious) seconds are the miniatures. They have a real pilot and helicopter, and it looks like the same guy in the later Digby movie, for the other scenes. IMHO, the pilot looks to be Barry Bird (rather than Ken Gregory or even John Crewdson). Not many details available though.